# can ping but not ssh my openstack instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon

I want to instanciate a ubuntu-bionic cloud image that should be hosted by an internal VLAN connected to my external network through a router. Here are the commands I run to do that:

```
openstack router create myrouter

openstack network create private

openstack subnet create --dhcp --gateway 192.168.44.254 --dns-nameserver 195.83.126.2 --dns-nameserver 195.83.126.11 --subnet-range 192.168.44.0/24 --network private  --allocation-pool start=192.168.44.100,end=192.168.44.200 private-subnet

openstack router set --external-gateway provider myrouter 

openstack router add subnet myrouter private-subnet

openstack server create --image 'Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)' --net private --key-name ansible-master-ansible --flavor small --security-group k8s-security-group srv01

openstack floating ip create provider

openstack server add floating ip srv01 192.168.13.211
```

where `k8s-security-group` is a security group that allows `ssh` and `icmp` protocols and `ansible-master-ansible` is a ssh key pair that I generated through `ssh-keygen` and uploaded on my openstack server. Both security group and ssh key pair have been tested successfully in previous tests when my host is directly behind the external network.

Basically, all the components are built. However, I **can** ping my instance but I **can  not** ssh with a `permission denied (publickey)` error. Looking at the log of my newly created instance I can read the following error message:

`ci_info: no authorized ssh keys fingerprints found for user ubuntu`

which seems to indicate that my ssh key was not injected properly in my instance even if in the summary of the instance the key appears to be present. Would you have any idea of what is wrong with my commands ?

PS: The same error occurs when those steps are performed using 1) `Horizon` GUI or 2) `ansible` openstack modules

[EDIT] same problem with a centos 7